# Echo all rows from column

Tags: php, mysql, row, echo

I need to echo all rows from SQL column.

Here is my PHP

```
$query2="SELECT * FROM field_activity WHERE field_id='$fetch'";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){
    $activity = $row['activity'];
    $cr_date = date_create($row['date']);
    $for_date = date_format($cr_date, 'F j, Y');
    $amount = $row['amount'];
    $acres_complete = $row['acres_complete'];
    $duration = $row['duration'];
    $status = $row['status'];
}
```

Here is my HTML output..

```
<?php
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td width='16%'><strong>Date</strong></td>";
    echo "<td width='16%'>$for_date</td>";
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    echo "<td width='16%'><strong>Activity</strong></td>";
    echo "<td width='16%'>$activity</td>";
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    echo "<td width='16%'><strong>Amount</strong></td>";
    echo "<td width='16%'>$amount</td>";
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    echo "<td width='16%'><strong>Acres Complete</strong></td>";
    echo "<td width='16%'>$acres_complete</td>";
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    echo "<td width='16%'><strong>Duration</strong></td>";
    echo "<td width='16%'>$duration</td>";
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    echo "<td width='16%'><strong>Status</strong></td>";
    echo "<td width='16%'>$status</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

This only displays one of the rows (the latest row) from the column.. I want it to display all rows..

Comment: echo inside the while loop, you just overwrite your strings with the $row array each time, so only see the last row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually do the echoing in the loop.  If you move all of the `echo` statements to the end of the `while` loop, it will work exactly as you expect.  You also need `<table>` and `</table>`.

Answer (score 0):

Please embed your one row HTML echos into the while loop and everything will be done

OR

You can build your html string in the loop and echo your html string elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding your variables in your while loop, so only the last value will be stored in your variables.

Try this:

```
$query2="SELECT * FROM field_activity WHERE field_id='$fetch'";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){

    $activity = $row['activity'];
    $cr_date = date_create($row['date']);
    $for_date = date_format($cr_date, 'F j, Y');
    $amount = $row['amount'];
    $acres_complete = $row['acres_complete'];
    $duration = $row['duration'];
    $status = $row['status'];

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td width='16%'><strong>Date</strong></td>";
    echo "<td width='16%'>$for_date</td>";
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    echo "<td width='16%'><strong>Activity</strong></td>";
    echo "<td width='16%'>$activity</td>";
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    echo "<td width='16%'><strong>Amount</strong></td>";
    echo "<td width='16%'>$amount</td>";
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    echo "<td width='16%'><strong>Acres Complete</strong></td>";
    echo "<td width='16%'>$acres_complete</td>";
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    echo "<td width='16%'><strong>Duration</strong></td>";
    echo "<td width='16%'>$duration</td>";
    echo "</tr><tr>";
    echo "<td width='16%'><strong>Status</strong></td>";
    echo "<td width='16%'>$status</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}
```

Additionally, this is not very good code.

Comment: Correct, just did not want to confuse Chad.